# Android check if Spanned objects are equal

Tags: android, spannable, spanned

How can I check if two Spanned objects are equal (they have the same content and spans applied)? I rather not implement the `equals(Spanned span)` method. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The span classes in Android lack `equals` and `hashCode` methods. I don't know why. Maybe it was just an oversight? There is also a bug in the `SpannableStringBuilder.equals()` method.

The workaround is exactly what you feared. If you use, for example, `AbsoluteSizeSpan` you need to extend it and add `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Use your version instead of the framework's version when adding spans to the `SpannableStringBuilder`:

```
import android.os.Parcel;


public class AbsoluteSizeSpan extends android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan {


    public AbsoluteSizeSpan(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public AbsoluteSizeSpan(int size, boolean dip) {
        super(size, dip);
    }

    public AbsoluteSizeSpan(Parcel src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        AbsoluteSizeSpan that = (AbsoluteSizeSpan) o;

        if (getSize() != that.getSize()) return false;
        return getDip() == that.getDip();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getSize();
        result = 31 * result + (getDip() ? 1 : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the Android framework's `SpannableStringBuilder.equals()` method, a list of sorted spans in compared to a list of unsorted spans . To fix this, override `SpannableStringBuilder.equals()`:

```
public class SpannableStringBuilder extends android.text.SpannableStringBuilder {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Spanned &&
                toString().equals(o.toString())) {
            Spanned other = (Spanned) o;
            // Check span data
            Object[] otherSpans = other.getSpans(0, other.length(), Object.class);
            Object[] spans = getSpans(0, length(), Object.class);
            if (spans.length == otherSpans.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
                    Object thisSpan = spans[i];
                    Object otherSpan = otherSpans[i];
                    if (thisSpan == this) {
                        if (other != otherSpan ||
                                getSpanStart(thisSpan) != other.getSpanStart(otherSpan) ||
                                getSpanEnd(thisSpan) != other.getSpanEnd(otherSpan) ||
                                getSpanFlags(thisSpan) != other.getSpanFlags(otherSpan)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else if (!thisSpan.equals(otherSpan) ||
                            getSpanStart(thisSpan) != other.getSpanStart(otherSpan) ||
                            getSpanEnd(thisSpan) != other.getSpanEnd(otherSpan) ||
                            getSpanFlags(thisSpan) != other.getSpanFlags(otherSpan)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add your override versions of the span classes to your version of `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why doesn't the Android framework provide proper means to compare SpannableStrings? I just want to write some unit tests in peace without shedding this many tears...